# How to set keyboard shortcut for extract local variable in Visual Studio without ReSharper (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using VisualStudio2019 for writing C# code. Specifically, I am working with an older project, so I need to do a lot of refactoring.

One of the most common things I need to do is introducing local variables to break down long call chain lines. To do so I currently select the part I want to break down, then right-click on it and select `Quick Actions and Refactorings...` > `Introduce local...` > `Introduce local for abc.xyz`.

Since I need this a lot, I would like to create a keyboard shortcut for this. However, I have searched in the keyboard mappings under `Tools` > `Options...` > `Environment` > `Keyboard`, but was unable to find a command for this.

Is there some kind of trick that I can use to set a keyboard shortcut for this? Or is this not possible in the vanilla version of VisualStudio?

Comment: Sounds like you would need to write an extension that allows binding a keyboard shortcut to that refactoring action.